# IncreasingPriceCrowdsale breaking TimedCrowdsale

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts

For reasons I can't figure out why open-zeppelin's `IncreasingPriceCrowdsale` and `TimedCrowdsale` seem to be conflicting with each other.  Here is a basic version of the Crowdsale contract I'm working with:

```
contract MyCrowdsale is Crowdsale, MintedCrowdsale, TimedCrowdsale, FinalizableCrowdsale, IncreasingPriceCrowdsale{

    Crowdsale(_rate_initial, _wallet, _mintableToken) 
    TimedCrowdsale(_openingTime, _closingTime) 
    IncreasingPriceCrowdsale(_rate_initial, _rate_final)
```

When `IncreasingPriceCrowdsale` isn't there everything works fine.  However when `IncreasingPriceCrowdsale` and `TimedCrowdsale` are there I get an error being thrown in the constructor in `TimedCrowdsale.sol` that `require(openingTime >= block.timestamp)`.

```
constructor(uint256 openingTime, uint256 closingTime) internal {
    // solium-disable-next-line security/no-block-members
    require(openingTime >= block.timestamp);
```

I'm initializing `openingTime`  to `web3.eth.getBlock('latest').timestamp + 20` which works fine when `IncreasingPriceCrowdsale` isn't there.

Any ideas how to fix this?